# Trying to create a grads script and getting error " Expected end of statement " how can I solve it?

Tags: vbscript

This is a screenshot of what I'm getting the error:

[image: Grads error]

The file name of the script it's coming with the grads program.

```
gradsgui.vbs
```

The content of the file the script:

```
' Lightweight script to call actual executables down bellow. Eventually it
' could include the same functionality of the Perl version. Now it seats in
' the very top, above Contents/

Dim objFileSystem, objFILE

' Find out where we actually are
' ------------------------------
ScriptPath = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, _
             Len(WScript.ScriptFullName) - Len(WScript.ScriptName))

' Get the current version from file
' ---------------------------------
Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.fileSystemObject")
Set objFILE = objFileSystem.OpenTextFile(ScriptPath & "Contents\Cygwin\Versions\Current@", 1)
Versions = Split(objFILE.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
Version = Left(Versions(0),Len(Versions(0))-1)
objFile.Close
Set objFileSystem = Nothing

' Actual executable path
' ----------------------
ActualPath = ScriptPath & "Contents\Cygwin\Versions\" & Version & "\i686\" 
ExecutableName = Left(WScript.ScriptName,Len(WScript.ScriptName)-4) & ".exe"
ExecutableFullName = ActualPath & ExecutableName
' WScript.echo "Running <" & ExecutableFullName & ">"

' Command line arguments
' ----------------------
Set ArgObj = WScript.Arguments
sArgCount = ArgObj.Count
args = " "
For x = 0 To sArgCount - 1
  args = args & " " & ArgObj(x)
Next
Set ArgObj = Nothing
Set xsize = 650 500

'Start actual application down below
'-----------------------------------
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'objShell.Run "%COMSPEC% /k" & ExecutableFullName & args
objShell.Run ExecutableFullName & args
Set objShell = Nothing
```

The line that I added that give the error is:

```
set xsize = 650 500
```

If I type this command in the console window when running the `grads.exe` it will work fine. But using the script it's giving me this error.

What i did is adding to the end of the file script two lines:

```
'Start actual application down below
 '-----------------------------------
 Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 Set env = objShell.Environment("PROCESS")
 env("xsize") = "650 500"
 ' objShell.Run "%COMSPEC% /k" & ExecutableFullName & args
 objShell.Run ExecutableFullName & args
 Set objShell = Nothing
```

The lines i added are:

```
Set env = objShell.Environment("PROCESS")
env("xsize") = "650 500"
```

But they are not doing anything. It's not opening the new window in this size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're mixing VBScript and CMD commands here. You probably mean to set `xsize=650 500` as an environment variable, but in VBScript the `Set` keyword is used for assigning objects to variables, not for defining variables in general like in CMD.

Try defining the variable in the [process environment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd7hxfdd%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), so that it's inherited by the child process you're starting:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set env = objShell.Environment("PROCESS")
env("xsize") = "650 500"
objShell.Run ExecutableFullName & args
```

Comment: I added this to the part in the script file say: Start actual application down below at the bottom added this lines you wrote but what it does is just running the console window twice. I guess i messed it up.

Comment: @DanielHamutel Of course you need to *replace* the code from `set xsize = 650 500` to the end of the file with the code above.

Comment: Ansgar if you can look please i updated my question with what i did. I added the two lines in the end but it's not doing anything when running this file script. It's just showing the console window without doing this two lines the Set env....and the env("xsize....

Comment: @DanielHamutel That looks correct. Check if your command works as intended. Echo the commandline to inspect it for mistakes (`WScript.Echo ExecutableFullName & args`), and uncomment the `Run` statement that executes the commandline via `%COMSPEC% /k` (comment or remove the other one).